# IIS Express Internal Server Error 500.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on building up this website and i keep hitting this 500.0 issue. I've tried installing IIS, re-installing VS, and even re-installing windows (it was time to do it anyway so the timing worked out).

The weird part is that i do not get it on all API endpoints, so far just one. I built out the api first and am testing while i'm building the front-end.

Model:

```
public class RoleAssignment {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public int TEC { get; set; }
    public DateTime? voidtime { get; set; }
}
```

Repository code:

```
    public async Task<RoleAssignment[]> GetServiceHistoryAsync(ServiceHistoryQuery query)
    {
        var result = _db.RoleAssignments.Where(x => !x.voidtime.HasValue);

        //only get requested TECs
        result = result.Where(x => x.TEC > query.Start && x.TEC <= (query.Start + query.Take));

        return await result.ToArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);//breaks here
    }
```

[Link to request trace](https://1drv.ms/u/s!As7mnQwZNDz48S9ZVWhICD9ghHZx)

[Link to 500 error](https://1drv.ms/u/s!As7mnQwZNDz48TAzjiLxbpRocQrK)

I've been spinning my wheels trying to figure this out for like a week now, Anyone have ideas as to what may be happening?

Comment: 500.0 comes from the web app itself in most cases, so no wonder your changes at IIS Express does not work. Read the error page and it contains more info.

Comment: I understand that, the error page it gives isn't useful. I'll post that as well

Comment: "Detailed Error Information" clearly indicates that the error comes from your controller, where it is very likely that an exception occurred but you never handled it (as the code indicates). Debug it.

Comment: I have been debugging it..... And i know for a fact that it is happening on the return statement of `GetServiceHistoryAsync` in the repo.